# Using AHP 2.0 in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I am using the AHP add-on and ModelBuilder.

I am making the model in ArcGIS which deals with Multi-Criteria Decision Making Analysis (MCDM). For the part of assigning weights to criteria I am thinking to use AHP method. I have found AHP 2.0 add-on on codesharing.arcgis.com. It seems it works fine. 
I have been thinking to include this in ModelBuilder. So when model comes to this part where AHP should be used, it will then open AHP 2.0 add-on. The user will work withing AHP as usuall and then once the criteria weights are caluclated it will be proceed further by taking these weights and caluclate the rest of MCDM.

How do I do this?

I anticpate that Python should be used here. I am familiar with this languge, but have not used it to establish the connection from one tool to another. In arcgis help website I have found the page - Integration external program within ModelBuilder. Here it explains the integration R program within ModelBuilder. I guess something similar has to be done in my case.

Do any of you have some tips, etc.. how this could be done?

Comment: Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about the site.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.